# cross reference with xr fails (ShareLatex)

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I try to use xr for cross referencing, and I get question marks instead of the reference and a warning:

```
Reference updateEq on page 1
undefined on input line 93
```

on the document i am referring to (filename is comet_main_NIPS.tex) I use (as suggested on posts on the web):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}
```

and my equation is defined with:

```
\begin{equation}
    \newW = \W^t +\eta G.
\label{updateEq}
\end{equation}
```

on the document I am referring from, I use:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{comet_main_NIPS}
```

and

```
some text \ref{updateEq} some text
```

Thanks a-lot for the assistance!

EDIT2:
NOticed also another Warning

```
Warning: File 'tmp2.aux' not found or empty
```

Which focused the issue on my sharelatex environment

EDIT1: As suggested in comments here is a tiny example:

File: tmp2.tex

```
\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section{SECTION}
Here is an equation
\begin{equation}
    3 = 2+1 
\label{eq321}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

File tmp1.tex

```
\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

%% packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{tmp2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section{SECTION}
\subsection{TBD}
TBD \eqref{eq321} TBD
\subsection{TBD}
TBD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try compiling the document containing the equation (again?) and then compile the referring document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  You've given us a lot of information; thank you.  All that would help is a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so that we can jump right in to trying to solve your problem.

Comment: is the `comet_main_NIPS.aux` file available, and what warnings do you get in the log?

Comment: @Mico no, only in the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in comments with @Heiko I understood the issue was related to sharelatex environment.

WRT minimal example:
I downloaded the aux file generated for the tmp2 compilation. Renamed it to tmp2.aux, and uploaded it to the ShareLatex project. Afterwards, issue was solved.

Answer (score 3):

## Package `xr-hyper`

Both files are using package `hyperref`, then `xr-hyper` can be used:

File `tmp1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}              

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\externaldocument{tmp2}

\begin{document}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{TBD} 
TBD \ref{eq321} TBD or \eqref{eq321}
\subsection{TBD}
TBD
\end{document}
```

Package `xr-hyper` needs to be loaded *before* `hyperref`.

## Package `zref-xr`

The external cross-reference module `zref-xr` of package `zref` can also be used for importing normal LaTeX labels. Package `zref-xr` supports the label extensions by packages `hyperref`/`nameref`, `titleref` and `ntheorem`.

These packages must be present, before external references are imported via `\zexternaldocument` to load them with the correct internal label format. Since `nameref` is usually loaded by `hyperref` via `\AtBeginDocument`, it can be loaded explicitly before `\zrefexternaldocument`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref} 

\usepackage{zref-xr}

\zxrsetup{tozreflabel=false, toltxlabel=true, verbose}
\zexternaldocument*{tmp2}

\begin{document}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{TBD} 
TBD \ref{eq321} TBD
\subsection{TBD}   
TBD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of the methods you suggested have worked (still get question marks). If it will be beneficial, i can add some log files outputs. (Not sure where to uploaded them though). Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user2476373 You can edit your question and add error/warning messages and/or log outputs there.

Comment: Thanks. Here are the warnings

`Package zref-xr Warning: File 'tmp2.aux' not found or empty,`
`(zref-xr)                labels not imported on input line 13.`
``
`LaTeX Warning: Reference 'eq321' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.`
``
`LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.`

Comment: @user2476373 What's the difficulty to understand the first warning? Have you forgotten to run LaTeX on the other file `tmp2`?

Comment: I have run it on the first file. I use www.sharelatex.com, for editing and compiling. Maybe it is related then..

Answer (score 2):

As @user2476373 and @Heiko suggested, this is a ShareLatex issue. Here's their suggestion regarding how to fix that:
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Kb/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_ShareLaTeX

Overleaf.com , one of the alternatives to sharelatex, deals with this issue slightly differently - see here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/example-using-xr-package-on-overleaf/tzzwtzrkjcpm#.WGjTQrZ95sO

Comment: As it stands it is more like of a comment, but since nobody has provided the link you have shown this is an answer. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I tried to write it as a comment, but it didn't let me since I don't have a good enough reputation...

Comment: Not yet ;-) That's why I did not vote to delete your post. It's an useful link, indeed (although I am not using ShareLaTeX etc. at all)